# is there a way to say LINQ that list is sorted...?

Tags: c#, linq

I'll have some big data in database and i need to group items by indexes,
for example

```
data[0] = > property_1 = 'zxc', property_2='xxx'
```

in database i have record which looks like:

```
data[0]/property_1/zxc
data[1]/property_1/zzz
data[0]/property_2/xxx
data[3]/property_1/ooo
```

so i can sort them in database (it is fast, select statement get 1 second only)
but if i want to grup them in linq it is very slow

important: for some reasons i can not grup them in database, i have to do it in application

Comment: Does the column have an index?

Comment: not,
my task is to group them somehow in application
i think if linq knows that items are sorted that would be faster...

Comment: Where is your linq? What do you use to communicate with SQL? Are you using LINQ-TO-SQL or Linq-To-Objects?

Comment: no, no, no. Ado.net, just query select * from... with orderd
i use linq in application (in memory of computer...)

Comment: _"for some reasons i can not group them in database"_ Maybe you want to ask instead how you can do that. Or is it a requrement that you have to select all records?

Comment: no, i just must not do it in database. it has to be done in application

Comment: yes i know ;) but my task is to do it in application, believe me i would do that in database if i could

Comment: @SharkyShark: name the method where you retrieve the data `GetDataSortedByIndex`. This plus a proper documentation header is absolutely sufficient.

Comment: LINQ to Objects `GroupBy` is quite fast, probably you should show more concrete example of what are you doing in order to see why it is slow.

Comment: lets say i'll have some 500 000 record like in my question and i will have to sort them by index and then by  path, where path can be differenent (like data[0]/data[1]/PropertyA, data[0]/PropertyA, data[1024]/data[12]/PropertyB ...

Comment: then just don't use linq. write a simple loop with a sensor variable that starts a new group whenever the index changes. will be faster, cleaner, and uses the "knowledge" that input is presorted.

Comment: @SharkyShark - Can you please use the `@` notifications when replying to someone? It's hard to follow who you're replying to otherwise.

Comment: @SharkyShark - Something seems wrong with your code. If you can sort and query data in under a second and bring it in to memory then a group by in memory should be much faster than a second. You need to show us your code to really figure out the issue. Richard's answer might have helped you, but we can't see why without your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. And `Enumerable.GroupBy` cannot make use of such knowledge.

But, as you know the input is sorted, you can write a less general `GroupBy` like method for your case where the assumption is made.

(But doing the group by on the database would be better.)

Such a custom group by, assuming in key order, would look something like:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> InputOrderedGroupBy<T, TKey>(
                          this IEnumerable<T> input, 
                          Func<T, TKey> keyExtractor) {
  TKey currKey = default(TKey);
  Grouped<T, TKey> res = null;
  foreach (var t in input) {
    var thisKey = keyExtractor(t);
    if (res == null || thisKey != currKey) {
      if (res != null) {
        yield return res;
      }
      res = new Grouped<T, TKey>();
      res.Key = currKey = thisKey;
    }
    res.Collection.Add(t);
  }
  if (res != null) {
    yield return res;
  }
}
```

where `Grouped<T, TKey>` is some implemention of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`.

Comment: ok im trying to do it my way, i just had hope that there is some possibility to say to linq, that list is already sorter so when it come to another index (which is string) then don't try to compare it to other 490k records...

Comment: Is that a typo *new new Grouped<T, TKey>()*? ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo: no, it is some (custom) implementation of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`

Comment: And the constructor is called with *new new*? Very new or totally new? Seems to be very custom indeed ;o)